# Ionic start a project in browser

Tags: cordova, setup-project, ionic-framework

I a new to ionic framework.

I downloaded a sample project from github

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-angular-cordova-seed

And then I wanna test it on browser

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

```
$ionic serve
```

The terminal show

```
Running serve task...
Running dev server at http://0.0.0.0:8100
Running live reload server at http://0.0.0.0:35729
```

and chrome open a new tab with URL: localhost:8100

The page show No data received with Error code : Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

anyone has ideas on it?

note that I tried other sample project form github, same thing happened.

Comment: You could use 'ripple' emulator

Comment: I tried different method. However, I am having the same result. Finally, I use the nginx to run a web server and run the html code.

Comment: then maybe your firewall is doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use python -m SimpleHTTPServer inside of www directory instead of ionic serve , it works for me

Comment: @akumapunk gives a correct answer as well. I mark this answer correct due to it is the simplest method and gives similar result as ionic serve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I called 'ionic serve' from the 'www' folder instead of the root of the project.  Make sure you are calling the serve command from the right location.

Comment: I am running the serve command according to this page instruction.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

There said "Testing your app in a browser is as simple as running the serve command in your project's root folder."

Anyway I tried to run at WWW folder. Same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the problem is with ionic's serve task, but what I do is, use the command that is built in cordova

```
cordova prepare && cordova serve
```

I use cordova prepare just to make sure the latest changes are served

And I also recommend using Ripple when working like this

Comment: It gives Package Metadata table on web browser. Select either ios or android could run the application.